# Get a sum of values from a CSV file

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I am trying to turn a CSV file in the following format:

```
   Unnamed: 0 Unnamed: 1 Unnamed: 2 Unnamed: 3 Unnamed: 4 Unnamed: 5  
0         HDB          1        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN   
1         NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN   
2         NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN   
3         HDB          1        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN   
4         NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN   
5         NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN   
6         NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN   
7         LPO          1       VLPO          1        NaN        NaN   
8         LPO          1        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN   
9         LGP          1        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN   
10        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN
```

To a CSV file that says

```
HDB 2
LPO 2
LGP 1
VLPO 1
```

Would it be easiest to try to make a dictionary first, and then make some kind of rule that would add up numbers for existing strings?

If so, what kind of function would do this?

So far I tried

```
import pandas as pd

reader = pd.read_csv('Book1.csv')

d={}
for column in reader:
    d[column[0]]=column[1:]
print d
```

Comment: Is your example actually meant to represent the CSV file (if not - could you please provide such an example) as it looks more like a copy/paste of a DataFrame

Comment: what is the aggregation logic? Just counting each string? What about the integer values?

Answer (score 3):

A one-liner using pandas builtin functions is:

```
reader.stack().value_counts()
```

`stack` pivots a DataFrame into a Series with a hierarchical index which then allows us to use the `value_counts` function. That's necessary because DataFrames don't support `value_counts`.

Note that this counts the frequency of the value `1` which appears in your example. You can easily filter the non-string indices to get to your expected output.

Answer (score 0):

```
temp = []
d = {}
with open('data', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        line=line.strip()
        # remove first column
        line = line.split(',')[1:]
        # get rid of "Nan"
        line = [x for x in  line if x != "NaN"]
        # put data into sublists of 2
        if line:
            line =  [line[i:i + 2] for i in range(0, len(line), 2)]
            temp.extend(line)

# unpack sublists and put into dictionary 
for  el in temp:
    k, v = el
    if k in d.keys():
        d[k]  += int(v)
    else:
        d[k] = int(v)

with open('data.csv', 'w', newline='') as fp:
    a = csv.writer(fp, delimiter=',')
    for t in d.items():
        a.writerows([t])

data.csv contains now:

LGP,1
HDB,2
VLPO,1
LPO,2
```